# How to save object as child of sub-collection reference in mongoose?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, firebase, mongoose

I have been searching for two days and could not get hint or solution for my problem.

In firebase we use db reference and sub-reference to store object at specific path and collection. I want to do same in mongodb and node app. Let me explain my problem with example.

I have mongodb with collections of users, messages, orders.

MessageModel

```
'use strict';
 var mongoose = require('mongoose'),
    Schema = mongoose.Schema,
    ObjectId = Schema.ObjectId;

var messageSchema = mongoose.Schema({
    ObjectId: ObjectId,
    sender_id: String,
    receiver_id: String,
    sender_name: String,
    receiver_name: String,
    time_stamp: String,
    message_text: String,
    is_seen: String,
    channel_id: String,
    message_type: String
})
;
var Message = mongoose.model('Message', messageSchema);
var exports = module.exports = Message;
```

Now I want to use message as child of messages/RUNTIME_GENERATED_ID/message.

In firebase I just put reference and save data and firebase automatically creates sub-collection if there is none with same name. I want to do same in mongodb using mongoose.

Answer (score 0):

Here are the simple two options that can solve your problem:
1) Add parent_id field in your collection and in parent_id save the mongo object id of a parent message document.

2)You can create child_messages property of type array and can push children messages full document into the child_message array.

I hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks Zeeshan for answering,  I want to make db structure like firebase collection so while querying I can get data directly with no searching cost. What I want to do is save each single chat messages in a single collection which should be child of parent collection. for example my db structure should be like this 
    Chats/user1_user2/[message1, message2]

Comment: If you want to get messages in just one query you can use option 2